# How can I display show/hide elements when user is registered?

Tags: users, registered

I'd like to change some elements in my header when the user is registered.

I have both codes of the element, one when unregistered and the other when the user is registered, but I don't know how to make them switch.

Any help?

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to do this based on registered vs unregistered status because all users are anonymous until they log in. If you mean "logged in" vs "not logged in" then ...

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
  // logged in content
} else {
  // not logged in content
}
```

## Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in